# GeoServer datastore password management

Tags: geoserver

From the documentation is an example of a "crypt1" password.

As an example, the password `geoserver` is encrypted to `crypt1:KWhO7jrTz/Gi0oTQRKsVeCmWIZY5VZaD`

We are using this level of security at our organization.  What we currently do is change the password to our datastores using the GeoServer interface.

What we would like to do is not use the GUI feature to update our datastore passwords, but instead enter the encrypted passwords directly into the datastore files.

We have the masterpw available to us in plain text.

What we are looking for is a procedure to take a plain text password "datastorepassword" and run a procedure to generate the encrypted password for the datastore and manually enter it in the datastore.xml.  We do not want to use the GeoServer GUI.

1. Receive new password in plaintext
2. Run a procedure to encrypt the password to the desired format:
   `crypt1:KWhO7jrTz/Gi0oTQRKsVeCmWIZY5VZaD`
3. Manually change the datastore.xml entry.

How can I do this?

Comment: It should be reasonable easy to look at the GeoServer source code and find the required method to call, I'd start by looking at https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/f1c7ce169df7a6a0400ab3406a00b5c3e2c61a82/src/security/security-tests/src/test/java/org/geoserver/security/password/GeoserverPasswordEncoderTest.java#L257

Comment: Oh, and I wouldn't use Weak PBE unless you have to due to arms limitation issues

Comment: zakariah1, did you ever find a full solution for this?  I looked at the GeoServer source/tests but is there a recommended way to do this cleanly?  Seems like it would be a mess.